# Evil samples of subtly broken C++ code

Tags: c++

I need some samples of bad C++ code that will illustrate violation of good practices. I wanted to come up with my own examples, but I am having a hard time coming up with examples that are *not contrived, and where a trap is not immediately obvious* (it's harder than it seems).

Examples would be something like:

1. Not defining copy constructor for classes with `std::auto_ptr` members, and using `std::auto_ptr` members with forward-declared classes.
2. Calling virtual functions from a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly).
3. Overloading a template function.
4. Circular references with `boost::shared_ptr`.
5. Slicing.
6. Throwing exceptions from C callbacks (directly or indirectly).
7. Floating point comparison for equality.
8. Exception safety of constructors with raw pointer members.
9. Throwing from destructors.
10. Integer overflow when compiled on different architectures (mismatch of `size_t` and `int`).
11. Invalidating a container iterator.

...or any other evil thing you can think of.

I'd appreciate some pointers to existing resources, or a sample or two.

Comment: I think by "overloading a template function" you mean "specializing a function template."  Overloading good.  Specialization bad.

Comment: @James yes, I mainly had overloading and specializing at the same time in mind.

Comment: The [Guru of the Week articles](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/) are an _excellent_ source of oddly or perniciously broken C++ code.

Comment: BTW throwing an exception from a callback is not necessarily bad. Exception may propagate freely up to the top level if the whole chain is "exception-proof".

Comment: @valdo Actually I had the case where there is C code was sandwiched between the throw/catch clause and the throw site, and the throwing of exception always resulted in terminate(), which I think happens when you have C code compiled without `-fexceptions`. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19620

Comment: Floating point equality comparison is not a C++ specific thing.

Comment: @MAK Yes, but I'd say it's a gray area relevancy-wise. Imagine you template function that worked perfectly with integers suddenly stops working with floating point numbers.

Comment: *How* not *to program in C++* is a bit dated but apropos to this poll-type question that does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) is an amazingly counterintuitive result of the way C++ parses things like this:

```
// Declares a function called "myVector" that returns a std::vector<float>.
std::vector<float> myVector(); 
// Does NOT declare an instance of std::vector<float> called "myVector"

// Declares a function called "foo" that returns a Foo and accepts an unnamed
// parameter of type Bar.
Foo foo(Bar()); 
// Does NOT create an instance of Foo called "foo" nor creates a Bar temporary

// Declares a function called "myVector" that takes two parameters, the first named
// "str" and the second unnamed, both of type std::istream_iterator<int>.
std::vector<float> myVector( 
    std::istream_iterator<int>(str),
    std::istream_iterator<int>()
);
// Does NOT create an instance of `std::vector<float>` named "myVector" while copying
// in elements from a range of iterators
```

This will surprise just about anybody who is not familiar with this particular quirk of the language (myself included when I started learning C++).

Comment: It still surprises me every time I see it. The trouble with anti-patterns is that you *don't* use them all the time, so they can easily get forgotten. You may have established coding habits that avoid the problem, but that doesn't mean you'll spot the problem easily in someone elses code.

Answer (score 16):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "A's foo!" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void foo() { std::cout << "B's foo!" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Base* o1 = new Base();
    Base* o2 = new Derived();
    Derived* o3 = new Derived();

    o1->foo();
    o2->foo();
    o3->foo();
}
```

And the output is:

```
A's foo!
A's foo!
B's foo!
```

Not sure if it has a name, but it sure is evil! :P

Comment: Oh dear, virtual function overload on const-ness. Good thing gcc has a warning for that: `-Woverloaded-virtual`.

Answer (score 13):

Code that are not exception safe can fail in ways that are not obvious to the readers of code:

```
// Order of invocation is undefined in this context according to the C++ standard.
// It's possible to leak a Foo or a Bar depending on the order of evaluation if one
// of the new statements throws an exception before their auto_ptrs can "own" it
accept_two_ptrs(std::auto_ptr<Foo>(new Foo), std::auto_ptr<Bar>(new Bar));

void MyClass::InvokeCallback(CallbackType cb)
{
    Foo* resource = new Foo;
    cb(resource); // If cb throws an exception, resource leaks
    delete resource;
}
```

Comment: The first example is really amusing, even people who thought about exception safety can be caught short...

Answer (score 9):

[This one came up earlier tonight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295529/detecting-eof-in-c-from-a-file-redirected-to-stdin/4295554#4295554).  As @[Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320/billy-oneal) pointed out on that post, looping on an input stream, checking only for `eof()`, can result in an infinite loop if an error occurs on the stream.  `good()` should be used instead.

**BAD:**

```
while( !cin.eof() ) {
   getline(cin, input);
}
```

**OK:**

```
while( cin.good() ) {
   getline(cin, input);
}
```

---

[credit: @James McNellis]

**EXCELLENT:**

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
}
```

Comment: Followed by:  **EXCELLENT:** `while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) { }`

Answer (score 7):

Overloading the assignment operator but [not handling self-assignment correctly](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html#faq-12.2).

Comment: Agreed - if you're doing reference-counting with copy-on-write, for example - a common way to avoid copying internals yet still have copy semantics - you need to be careful. With *any* reference counting, you need to ensure at least that you increment the source before you decrement/discard a destination which (if it's the same object as the source) you may still need.

Comment: :-O Something I never considered!

Answer (score 7):

What do you think the program will print?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    void f(int) { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

struct B: public A {
    void f(bool) { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f(true);
    b.f(1);
    A* a = &b;
    a->f(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer: `b`, `b`, `a`!  The first printout is obvious.  The second one is `b` because the definition of `B::f(bool)` hides the definition of `A::f(int)`.  The third one is `a` because overload resolution happens on the static type.

(source: Guru of the Week, but I can't find the article.)

Answer (score 5):

Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL, also called Koenig lookup) is not well understood by most C++ programmers and can cause some very unusual results, most notably when combined with templates.

I discussed one major pitfall of ADL in an answer to [What are the pitfalls of ADL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl)

---

There is a lot of complexity involved in overload resolution.  Problems frequently arise when using directives are used at namespace scope, especially `using namespace std`, since that namespace has a large number of entities with common names.

Here are two more recent examples of the `using namespace std` causing problems:

- [distance calculation error in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217733/distance-calculation-error-in-c/4217760#4217760)
- [why didn't the positive terms get displayed in this asbolute program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401878/why-didnt-the-positive-terms-get-displayed-in-this-asbolute-program/3401897#3401897)

Comment: Oh, I see you mentioned Guru of the Week in the comments :)

Answer (score 2):

This one, IMHO, is tricky too:

```
class Base {
int _value;

public:
    Base() {
        _value = g();
    }

    virtual int f() = 0;

    int g() { return f(); }
};

class Derived: Base {   
public:
    Derived(): Base()
    { /* init Derived */ }

    int f() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

your code will crash because of pure virtual method `f()` not implemented. The obvious reason is that Derived is not yet complete in the constructor, so you will end up calling the virtual pure `f()` and won't be detected by the compiler (usually, compiler complains if a pure virtual is invoked inside a constructor).

Anyway, it may happens that a virtual pure is invoked if you have complex constructor which invokes other member function and you don't have unit-tests in place.

Comment: Didn't you mean to put a call to `g()` in Base, rather than Derived?