# Which declaration is the standard in C++/C?

Tags: c++, c, declaration

Which of the following declaration is the standard and preferred?

```
int x = 7;
```

or

```
int x(7);
```

Comment: One compiles, the other does not. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: In C++, `int x{7};` is also valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int x(7);
```

is *not* the *valid* way of declaring & initializing a variable in C;

*I suggest you to get a good book for learning C and use a good compiler.*

Answer (score 1):

in c kind of langueges you normally use
int x = 7;

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this question as both C and C++, but the answers aren't really the same for the two.

In C, `int x(7);` simply doesn't work. It won't even compile. Since this form doesn't work at all in C, the preferred form is `int x = 7;`.

In C++, `int x(7);` works -- but you have to be careful, as this form can lead to the ["most vexing parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295704/179910); if whatever was in the parentheses could be interpreted as a type instead of a value, this would be parsed as declaring a function named `x` that returned an `int` instead of defining an `int` with the value specified in the parentheses. Likewise, if you leave the parens empty: `int x();` you end up with a function declaration.

C++ does have another form: `int x{7};`. Some call this "universal initialization". It does remove any ambiguity -- anything like `T id { x };` where `T` is a type *must* be a definition of a `id` with `x` as an initializer. Some people dislike this, however, because it introduces somewhat different semantics -- for example, "narrowing" conversions are prohibited in this case, so you can't blindly change existing code to use the new form. For example:

```
int x(12.34); // no problem
int y{ 12.34 }; // won't compile -- double -> int is a narrowing conversion
```

This isn't particularly likely to happen with a literal as I've shown above, but something like:

```
void f(double x) { 
    int y(x);
    // ...
```

...is rather more likely -- and still isn't allowed.

Unfortunately, going "back" to the C-style initialization doesn't cure all the possible problems either. At least in theory, it does copy initialization instead of direct initialization, so the type you're initializing must have a copy constructor available to do this initialization. For example:

```
class T {
    T(T const &) = delete;
public:
    T(int) {}
};

int main() {
    T t = 1;
}
```

This isn't officially allowed to work, because what it's supposed to do is use `T(int)` to create a temporary `T` object, then use `T(T const &)` to copy-construct `t` from that temporary. Since we've deleted the copy constructor, it can't (officially) be used. This can be particularly confusing, because nearly all compilers will normally do the job without using the copy constructor at all, so the code will *normally* compile and work just fine--but the minute you turn on the mode where the compiler tries to follow the standard as closely as possible, the code won't compile at all.

Some people find the changes in "uniform initialization" so off-putting that they recommend against using it at all. Personally, I prefer to use it and simply ensure that I'm not doing any narrowing conversions (or use an explicit cast if a narrowing conversion just can't be avoided).

Answer (score 0):

In general

```
int x = 7;
```

is the standard way, and the ONLY way in C.

However, in C++, you can initialize an int using x(7) in cases such as constructor initializer lists, where you have to invoke a 'constructor' for each variable you are initializing that way. For primitives, you do this with the x(7) syntax.